# Why am I getting a 403 Forbidden error using the AWS SDK when making a request in Laravel, but it works fine in Postman?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, laravel-8

I'm currently facing an issue while attempting to send a request to an Apigateway URL from within my Laravel application. I initially conducted successful tests using Postman, where I provided the necessary access_key and secret_key for authentication, and the data was sent without any problems.

However, when I tried to implement the same functionality in my Laravel project using the AWS SDK for PHP, I encountered a 403 Forbidden error.

I've provided the code I'm using below along with the libraries I've included. Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it?

```
    use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;
    use Aws\Signature\SignatureV4;
    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request as GuzzelReques;

    $url = env('APIGATEWAY_URL') . "/@connections/" . $request->connectionId;
    $region = env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION');
    $json = json_encode(["message" => "devolviendo prueba"]);

    $credentials = new Credentials(env('APIGATEWAY_ACCESS_KEY'),env('APIGATEWAY_SECRET_KEY'));

    $client = new Client();`your text`
    $request = new GuzzelReques('POST', $url, [], $json);
    $s4 = new SignatureV4("execute-api", $region);
    $signedrequest = $s4->signRequest($request, $credentials);
    $responseApi = $client->send($signedrequest);
```

**UPDATE**

I revisited the issue and found that the URL I used in Postman had one of the path segments in uppercase, which was different from how it was configured in the environment variable I was using. I made the necessary adjustment, and now the error has changed. Below, you'll find the initial lines of the trace generated by Laravel

```
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://api-id-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Test/@connections/LsYfDcZxIAMCEiA=` resulted in a `410 Gone` response in /var/app/current/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php:113

#0 /var/app/current/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php(72): GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request), Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), NULL, Array, NULL)
```

Comment: Please share the detailed error logs.

Comment: @xpetersue Hello, thank you for the reply. I've already provided a portion of the log generated by Laravel

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow  Why don't you just use the AWS SDK? I never understood people signing their own requests.

Comment: "Hello, thank you very much. However, I am using the AWS SDK. If you look at the code, the first two classes are part of the SDK. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching, I successfully found a way to sign the request and make it work. Just in case someone else needs it, I'll share the code I used for this. I also had to utilize the Credentials class and discovered that using the ApiGatewayManagementApiClient class was essential, here is the code

```
use Aws\ApiGatewayManagementApi\ApiGatewayManagementApiClient;
use Aws\Credentials\Credentials;

$apiGatewayUrl = env('APIGATEWAY_URL');
$region = env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION');
$accessKeyId = env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID');
$secretAccessKey = "MRrhp6WGNGacS+17kLNz9Tbz0kaTSEf7VIRpkYHH";
$connectionId = $request->connectionId;

// Credentials configuration
$credentials = new Credentials($accessKeyId, $secretAccessKey);

// Create an ApiGatewayManagementApiClient client
$client = new ApiGatewayManagementApiClient([
   'region' => $region,
   'credentials' => $credentials,
   'endpoint' => $apiGatewayUrl."@connections",
]);

// Request configuration
$requestConfig = [
    'ConnectionId' =>  $connectionId,
    'Data' => json_encode(["message" => "Generacion de prueba request "]),
];

$response = $client->postToConnection($requestConfig);
```